# Ruby/Rails break out of method inside loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rescue

I have two methods I use to sync categories to a 3rd party service.  The first method loops through everything and the second actually exports each category. If there is a failure, how do I break out of the loop completely?

```
def export_all
  Category.find_each do |c|
    export_category(c)
  end
end

def export_category(c)
  begin
    sync_category(c)
  rescue Exception => e
    # break out of `export_all` loop
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options for breaking out of a loop. Most simply, you can use `break` or `return` in your looping code.

In the context of your example above, it might be easier, if possible within the larger context of your application, to do the following:

```
def export_all
  Category.find_each do |c|
    begin 
      export_category(c)
    rescue SpecificErrorIsBetterThanGenericExceptionIfPossible => e
      break
    end
  end
end

def export_category(c)
  sync_category(c)
end
```

It appears from your question that you want the loop in your export_all method to break when an exception is encountered. In such a case, I prefer my break/error handling code at that level.